# Flutter: Stream and Isolate

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, dart-isolates

I am trying to Isolate `MyComplexObject` within a stream.
`MyComplexObject` has more Objects within it's class.

`MyComplexObject` Example:

```
class MyComplexObject {
 String documentID;
 Object1 object1;
 Object2 object2;
 Object3 object3;
 Object4 object4;
 Object5 object5;
 Object6 object6;
 Object7 object7;

 MyComplexObject({
 this.documentID;
 this.object1,
 this.object2,
 this.object3,
 this.object4,
 this.object5,
 this.object6,
 this.object7,
 });

 factory MyComplexObject.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  return MyComplexObject(
        documentID: documentSnapshot.documentID,
        object1: documentSnapshot.data['map1'],
        object2: documentSnapshot.data['map2'],
        object3: documentSnapshot.data['map3'],
        object4: documentSnapshot.data['map4'],
        object5: documentSnapshot.data['map5'],
        object6: documentSnapshot.data['map6'],
        object7: documentSnapshot.data['map7'],
  );
 }
}
```

My Stream function

```
Stream<MyComplexObject> streamMyComplexObject(String documentID) {
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        _db.collection(deviceStatesCollection).document(documentID);

    return documentReference
        .snapshots()
        .map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

      return MyComplexObject.fromFirestore(documentSnapshot);
    });
  }
```

and I use `streamMyComplexObject` with a `StreamBuilder`, is it possible to isolate the parsing/conversion of `MyComplexObject` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but maybe you looking for extension on your object: https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods

Comment: This may be the closest thing that is related to my question: https://speakerdeck.com/anvith/isolating-flutter-into-multithreading-effectively?slide=29

Comment: I'm not sure I see the purpose behind doing this. Using isolates in Dart is a tedious and error-prone task, so it should only be used if there is a long-running task with a high likelihood of blocking the main thread. It's also important to note that isolates in Dart do not share memory with the main thread, so all data that gets passed back and forth needs to do it via a dedicated communication channel. Setting up a stream to process and redirect that data is certainly possible, but also redundant if it's not absolutely necessary.